# Java code reflection and generation of façades for redirection of classes

Tags: java, reflection, facade

I have a bunch of classes in a huge product that I do not want to use and instead I want to redirect their uses to different classes. These classes (and interfaces) are mostly logging classes. E.g., `org.apache.log4j` classes were (long time ago) taken and imported into source under different package name, like `foo.org.apache.log4j`.

Now, I want to use some of the components that use these imported and renamed classes but without these imported and renamed classes. This is because the imported source is old and lacks functionality, so I cannot use it as it is. Also, having two different log4j implementations, the old imported one and original log4j, creates problems during configuration, etc.

My battle plan, so far, is to exclude the undesirable dependencies in `pom.xml` and somehow *auto-generate* façades that would replace the undesirable classes and would redirect to the original library. E.g., `foo.org.apache.log4j.Logger` would be replaced by a façade that inherits from `org.apache.log4j.Logger`.

Now, is there any kind of library or tool that would make it easy to traverse all existing classes defined by `foo.org.apache.log4j` and allow me to generate these façades, or do I have to implement everything on my own using reflection?

Comment: OK, why the close vote? What is wrong with this question?

Comment: I'm not the one who put the close vote, but it may be due to how you worded your question to ask for a "library or tool" after starting out talking about reflection.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wouldn't use a tool to generate these class as it's a once off.

Instead I would use the IDE to generate implementations and use re-factoring like replacing inheritance with delegation.  This will generate the facades you need without an additional tool.

e.g. Say you need a wrapper for a Map (This working IntelliJ but other may also do it)

```
class MyMap<K,V> extends Map<K,V> { // this doesn't compile but can be refactored
```

If I do "Replace inheritance with delegation" I get a wrapper which does compile

```
class MyMap<K,V> {
   private Map<K,V> map;

   public V get(K key) { return map.get(key); }

   // all the methods of map have been wrapped
}
```

Now say I want Map from a different package, but with the smae signature, I can change the import and it will use a different map package

```
class MyMap<K,V> implements somepackage.Map<K,V> {
    private some.other.pkg.Map<K,V> map;
    // all the delegation methods I need.
    // customise them as required.
}
```

Note: after inlining, there won't even be a significant performance penalty.

Comment: For anything under 20 classes to replace (which is the case if we're talking about a library like log4j) this seems to be the easiest solution.